# IndexError: list index out of range python

Tags: python

The follwoing code takes a log file and re-writes it in csv format:

```
file = open("C:\\Scripts\\logs\\SteelUsage2.bsu")
DataFile = open("C:\\Scripts\\MFGData90.csv","a+")
for line in file.readlines():   
    #print line
    line=line.strip()
    numbers=line.split()
    #print numbers
    #print numbers[0]
    #alpha = numbers [0]
    #print alpha
    StartHour= numbers[0]
    StartMinute= numbers[1]
    StartDay=numbers[2]
    StartMonth=numbers[3]
    StartYear=numbers[4]
    EndHour=numbers[5]
    EndMinute=numbers[6]
    Meters=numbers[10]
    #float(Meters)
    #round(Meters)
    #int(Meters)
    #print "before if "+Meters
    if Meters > "0.1":
        #print "after if "+Meters
        print StartDay+"/"+StartMonth+"/"+StartYear+","+StartMinute+":"+StartHour+","+EndMinute+":"+EndHour+","+Meters+"\n"
        #DataFile.write (StartDay+"/"+StartMonth+"/"+StartYear+","+"90"+","+Meters+","+StartMinute+":"+StartHour+","+EndMinute+":"+EndHour+"\n") 

DataFile.close()
file.close()
```

example log file:

```
 49 12 5 9 2016 14 15 5 9 2016 219.682
 14 15 5 9 2016 15 15 5 9 2016 0
 12 11 6 9 2016 45 11 6 9 2016 83.691
 46 11 6 9 2016 56 11 6 9 2016 41.125
 6 11 7 9 2016 7 11 7 9 2016 0
 7 11 7 9 2016 8 11 7 9 2016 0
 32 12 7 9 2016 32 12 7 9 2016 0
 33 12 7 9 2016 54 12 7 9 2016 50.823
```

example output:

```
5/9/2016,12:49,15:14,219.682

6/9/2016,11:12,11:45,83.691

6/9/2016,11:46,11:56,41.125

7/9/2016,12:33,12:54,50.823
```

but when the log file contains non integer characters like this:

```
 49 12 5 9 2016 14 15 5 9 2016 219.682
 NAME
 14 15 5 9 2016 15 15 5 9 2016 0
 12 11 6 9 2016 45 11 6 9 2016 83.691
 46 11 6 9 2016 56 11 6 9 2016 41.125
 6 11 7 9 2016 7 11 7 9 2016 0
 7 11 7 9 2016 8 11 7 9 2016 0
 32 12 7 9 2016 32 12 7 9 2016 0
 33 12 7 9 2016 54 12 7 9 2016 50.823
```

iget the follwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    StartMinute= numbers[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

where did i go wrong?
thanks!

Comment: Check `numbers` length ?

Comment: After line.split() add a line to print what numbers is: print( 'numbers %r' % (numbers,) ) that should show you what you need to know to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

after `numbers=line.split()` add a line with this test: 
`if len(numbers) < 11: continue`

Comment: 10 is not enough as with 10 elements you won't be able to get numbers[10] which is the 11th.

Answer (score 0):

So what do you want do to with the line with `NAME`

In fact when your script read it, you have :

```
>>> line = "NAME"
>>> line = line.strip()
>>> numbers = line.split()
>>> numbers
['NAME']
```

And therefore `numbers[1]` will raise an error as there is only one element in `numbers`

You might want to `continue` with the next line when there is not enough `numbers` in `line`:

```
if len(numbers) < 11:
    continue
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file = open("tst")
DataFile = open("tst_csv.csv","a+")
desired_size = 6
for line in file.readlines():   
    #print line
    line=line.strip()
    numbers=line.split()
    if not len(numbers) >= desired_size:
        continue
    #print numbers[0]
    #alpha = numbers [0]
    #print alpha
    StartHour= numbers[0]
    StartMinute= numbers[1]
    StartDay=numbers[2]
    StartMonth=numbers[3]
    StartYear=numbers[4]
    EndHour=numbers[5]
    EndMinute=numbers[6]
    Meters=numbers[10]
    #Meters = int(round(float(Meters))) not sure if you wanted to do this <--, int(), round(), float() etc... return copies and do not modify the original
    print "before if "+Meters
    if Meters > 0.1:
        #print "after if "+Meters
        print StartDay+"/"+StartMonth+"/"+StartYear+","+StartMinute+":"+StartHour+","+EndMinute+":"+EndHour+","+Meters+"\n"
        #DataFile.write (StartDay+"/"+StartMonth+"/"+StartYear+","+"90"+","+Meters+","+StartMinute+":"+StartHour+","+EndMinute+":"+EndHour+"\n") 

DataFile.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: @Alu Sure... if there is only one element in the list then you can only grab how many elements? You guessed it, ONE.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

You take line after line of your log and split is in separate parts. (11 in your case).

So if you want to access a part of the line which doesn't exist, you get an error. 
Try checking every line if it has all parts and access then.

I wouldn't suggest using continue, because its considered as bad practice.
It's better to explicitly do your stuff only when the number of elements is right.

```
numbers = line.split()
if len(numbers) >= 11:
  // Do your stuff
```